# Parsing XML documents of which the top elements contains a list of objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey

I have to query multiple URLs that return XML files that either contain one invoice, or a list of invoices (I know which URLs will return a list and which ones will return only a single invoice).

The format for a single invoice (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <invoice>
    <invoice-id>1</invoice-id>
</invoice>
```

The format for a list of invoices:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoices>
  <invoice>
    <invoice-id>1</invoice-id>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <invoice-id>2</invoice-id>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Jersey can process the first xml fragment automatically and convert it to a Java class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Invoice {
    @XmlElement(name="invoice-id")  
    Integer invoiceId;
}
```

This is done with the following code:

```
GenericType<JAXBElement<Invoice>> invoiceType = new GenericType<JAXBElement<Invoice>>() {};
Invoice invoice = (Invoice) resource.path("invoice_simple.xml").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(invoiceType).getValue();
```

The above WORKS.

Now I want to have an InvoiceList object as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class InvoiceList {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="invoices")
    @XmlElement(name="invoice")
    List<Invoice> invoices; 
}
```

This is where I run into problems; the InvoiceList.invoices remain null after:

```
GenericType<JAXBElement<InvoiceList>> invoicesType = new GenericType<JAXBElement<InvoiceList>>() {};
InvoiceList invoices = (InvoiceList) resource.path("invoices_simple.xml").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(invoicesType).getValue();      
// now invoices.invoices is still null!
```

I know that Jersey/JAXB can handle lists of objects, but it seems that it won't work if the top element contains the list.

So, my question is: How can I instruct Jersey to parse an xml file that consists of a list of invoice objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer is

Put `nillable = true` onto the `@XmlElement`.

```java
@XmlElement(name = "invoice", nillable = true)
List<Invoice> invoices;
```

And I would do like this. (You don't have to wrap an already wrapped collections.)

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Invoices {

    public List<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        if (invoices == null) {
            invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
        }
        return invoices;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "invoice", nillable = true)
    private List<Invoice> invoices; 
}
```

Some JAX-RS examples go like this

```java
@GET
@Path("/invoices")
public Invoices readInvoices() {
    // ...
}

@GET
@Path("/invoices/{invoice_id: \\d+}")
public Invoice readInvoice(@PathParam("invoice_id") final long invoiceId) {
    // ...
}
```